# VueJS Update Dom After Calling Simple Method Not Working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to dynamically change the color of buttons, when I click on them. I therefore added a custom class "active" that should only be assigned when the property isActive is set to true. On Click I want to call a method that changes the property to true and then update the dom to add the custom class. Any Help is appreciated ;)

```
<div v-for="(funktion, index) in funktions">
          <button class="btn btn-default wordcloud" 
                  :class="{ 'custom-active': funktion.isActive }" 
                  @click="activate(index)">{{funktion.name}}</button>
</div>
```

The method correctly updates the data but the dom doesn't update

```
export default {

  data() {
    return {
      funktions: [
          {
            name: "finanzen",
            isActive: false
          },
          {
            name: "management",
            isActive: false
          },
          {
            name: "testfield",
            isActive: false
           },
       ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    activate(index){
        this.funktions[index].isActive = true;
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing the index to the `activate` callback. Change it to:

```
@click="activate(index)">{{funktion.name}}</button>
```

If you were to look in your console you'd have an exception that would have given you a clue since you're trying to access an item an array with a non-number.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      funktions: [
          {
            name: "finanzen",
            isActive: false
          },
          {
            name: "management",
            isActive: false
          },
          {
            name: "testfield",
            isActive: false
           },
       ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    activate(index){
        this.funktions[index].isActive = true;
    },
 },
})
```

```css
.custom-active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(funktion, index) in funktions">
    <button class="btn btn-default wordcloud" 
      :class="{ 'custom-active': funktion.isActive }" 
      @click="activate(index)">{{funktion.name}}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry of course I already did this, its a mistake from the question, I'll edit. Any other ideas?

Comment: Then I'm unsure what you're asking since your code already adds the active class on click?

Comment: On click the data changes correctly but the Dom doesn't update. If I manually change the "isActive" to true the class gets assigned correctly on reload

Comment: The dom was updating fine for me

Comment: what the hell? well can't argue with that, no idea then